# RawBsonDocument as a query result

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I ran into a problem where I want an intermediate step between the server and the client. So I do not want to serialize the result on the server (e.g. `query.ToList`). I, therefore, want the query result as `RawBsonDocument` so I just have the raw bytes instead the data serialized as `BsonDocument`.

I'm currently using the Mongo C# driver but I haven't had much luck getting the result as raw bytes when I create a query.

**Example 1 (`RawBsonDocument` - OK)**

```
IAggregateFluent<RawBsonDocument> query = collection.Aggregate()
   .Sort(Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending("StartTime"))
   .Match(categoryFilter)
```

**Example 2 (`RawBsonDocument` - Fail)**

```
IAggregateFluent<RawBsonDocument> query = collection.Aggregate()
   .Sort(Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending("StartTime"))
   .Match(categoryFilter)
   .Project(new BsonDocument(new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
       {"Measurement.Time", "$Entities._time"},
       {"Measurement.Value", "$Entities.mes"}
   }))
```

In *Example 1* I can get the result in `RawBsonDocument`. When I start applying operators like `Group` or `Project` it forces me to get the result as `BsonDocument` (*Example 2*). How can I get the result as `RawBsonDocument` or just bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I do not think it is possible according to this:

> The high-level APIs that take a projection will always take the former. This is because, when determining how to handle a projection client-side, it is not enough to know what fields and transformations will take place. It also requires that we know how to interpret the projected shape as a .NET type. Since the driver allows you to work with custom classes, it is imperative that any projection also include the “interpretation instructions” for projecting into a custom class.

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/